# How I can show number of HTML elements is equal to JavaScript number?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have such function:

```
export const getBooksRating = (star) => {
    for(let i = 0 ; ;){
        if(i < star){
            i++
            if(i === star){
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For example `star` is a number `3`, so how i can `return` in this situation 3 tags `div` with some content? (i need to return number of `div === star`)

Comment: Why the `for(let i = 0 ; ;){` ?

Comment: What have you tried? How is it not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about something like this?

```js
Array(star).fill().map(() => <div></div>)
```

Comment: Exactly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With some content? Depends on what you mean.

This is one solution to return a string of divs:

```
var string;
for(let i = 0; i < star; i++){
  string += "<div id='divid-" + (i+1) + "'>";
}

for(let i = 0; i < star; i++){
  string += "</div>";
}
```

Output if star == 3:

```
<div id='divid-1'>
   <div id='divid-2'>
      <div id='divid-3'>

      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

If you don't want them to be nested, just use this in the first loop and delete the second:

```
string += "<div id='divid-" + (i+1) + "'></div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export const getBooksRating = (star) => {

  const divContent = 'hello world';

  // use string interpolation to put content inside the div
  const content = `<div>${divContent]</div>`

  return content.repeat(star);

}
```